# perl smartmatch on array literal

Tags: perl

```
slu@new-host:~ 19:59:33
❯ perl -e "print (2 ~~ (1, 2, 3))"
slu@new-host:~ 19:59:39
❯ perl -e "my @a = (1, 2, 3); print (2 ~~ @a)"
1
```

Admittedly the second form is not a whole lot more concise than the first, but I'm curious to know why the first one fails.

Comment: Adding `-w` warnings would give you a clue as to what is happening.

Comment: It says `Useless use of a constant (2) in void context at -e line 1.` Still unsure why it is a void context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1,2,3` is a list literal or a list operator, not an array literal. A list operator in scalar context returns that to which its last operand evaluates, so

```
print (2 ~~ (1, 2, 3))
```

means

```
print(2 ~~ 3)  # Plus two void context warnings
```

Given that

```
print (2 ~~ @a)
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
print(2 ~~ \@a)
```

you could use

```
print(2 ~~ do { my @a = (1,2,3); \@a })
```

or the near-equivalent but shorter

```
print(2 ~~ [1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works

```
slu@new-host:~ 20:00:31
❯ perl -e "print (2 ~~ [1, 2, 3])"
1
```